# reading txt files using ff library in R

Tags: r, ff

I have a large dataset (1.1GB) in tab seperated format. When I read this dataset into the program R using the normal read.table function:

```
data <- read.table(file="C:/Localdata/Postcode model/Data/FinalDataset.txt", 
                   header=TRUE, sep="\t")
```

it works fine. However, I wish to read it in using the ff function from the ff library so I use the code:

```
library(ff)
data <- read.table.ffdf(file="C:/Localdata/Postcode model/Data/FinalDataset.txt", 
                        header=TRUE, sep="\t")
```

There is no issue with loading the ff package and the function works fine. The error that is thrown up is:

`Error in read.table(header = FALSE, sep = "\t", file = 3L, fileEncoding = "",  : more columns than column names`

Why is this?

Comment: You might consider including the contents of the first few lines of your file, to make it easier for us to diagnose the problem.

Comment: The data has 16 columns, each with its own header. Two of the columns are string types and the rest numeric

Comment: Does `unique(count.fields('C:/Localdata/Postcode model/Data/FinalDataset.txt', sep='\t', comment.char=''))` return `16`?

Comment: it returns 16 17

so yeah, that's where the problem lies i'm guessing. 


read.table does read it in correctly but I need to use ffdf so a solution to why it's playing up would be much appreciated

Comment: Try adding `comment.char='#'` to the `read.table.ffdf` call. Maybe one of the lines of the txt file has a comment, and this would be interpreted as such by `read.table` but not, (by default) by `read.table.ffdf`.

Comment: didn't work unfortunately :(

Comment: It's worth inspecting those rows with 17 fields, then. For example with: `f <- 'C:/Localdata/Postcode model/Data/FinalDataset.txt'; i <- which(count.fields(f, sep='\t') == 17); do.call(rbind, lapply(i, function(x) read.table(f, header=FALSE, skip=x-1, nrows=1, sep='\t')))`.

Comment: Can you just manually put in a 17th header into your file?  Then read it in normally?